# C++ stringstream parsing

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am trying to read valid a user input from command prompt:

for example, valid user input is in following format:

getData <>

<> - any string type value

on Command Prompt:

e.g getData name   => Correct (only one parameter entered after getData as expected)
e.g getData name ID => InCorrect (more than one parameter entered after getData)
e.g getData          => InCorrect  (due to no parameter entered after getData)

How do I check for number of parameters? my code logic is as follow:

```
string cmd_input;

getline(cin, cmd_input)

stringstream ss(cmd_input);

string input;
string parameter;

 ss >> input; //getData
 ss >> parameter; //name
```

How do I go about valid/invalid checking? I don't want to run it through loop till EOF stream and count the number of parameter. I read up on peek() and not sure how it fits here. Also, I don't want to use vectors to store parameter.

Thanks!

Comment: "I don't want to run it through loop till EOF stream and count the number of parameter." Why not? Anyway, you don't need a loop - just read one more parameter; if that succeeds, there is one too many.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the state of the stream itself after you retrieve input. If the retrieval succeeded, it will be `true`. You want it to return `true` after two retrievals, but be `false` on the third.

```
if (!(ss >> input1) || input1 != "getData") { //... error : unexpected cmd
}
if (!(ss >> input2)) { //... error: no param
}
if (ss >> input3) { //... error: too many params
}
//... okay
```

Answer (score 1):

With the constraint of not using loops and not even `std::vector`, it could look the following way:

```
std::string line, command, arg1, arg2, arg3;

if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {

    std::istringstream is(line);
    if (is >> command) {
        std::string word;
        if (is >> arg1) {
            ...
            if (is >> arg2) {
                ...
                if (is >> arg3) {
                     ...
                }
            }
        }
    } // end of is >> command
}
```

---

Yet if you change your mind and decide to use `std::vector`, it could look like this:

```
std::string line, command;
std::vector<std::string> arguments;

if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {

    std::istringstream is(line);
    if (is >> command) {
        std::string word;
        while (is >> word)
            arguments.push_back(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: he clearly states he doesnt want to use vectors or loop to eof

Answer (score 0):

```
ss >> input;
if( ss.eof() )
    //no parameter code
else
{
    ss >> param;
    if( !ss.eof() )
         // too many param code
    else
         // good input
}
```

Comment: Actually, if there is no further argument, the input is also bad.

Comment: which is what the first if checks

Comment: Nope. If the input is, e.g., `"getData "` (note the extra space) there is just one word but no further parameter. Also, the error condition if `ss.eof()` is `true` after the first read is not necessarily that there is no parameter: reading `input` may have failed, too (e.g., when the line is empty or contains only spaces).

Comment: No. You always want to check for `std::ios_base::failbit` to see if the operation succeeded, e.g., by converting to `bool`. Only if you need to know if EOF was reached you'd use `eof()`. See Liho's, jxh's, or my answer for what he wants to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple test program reading `command`s. If the `command` is `getData` one argument is extracted and, if this is successful, any trailing whitespace is skipped. At this point the stream parsing the line is expected to have reached its end, i.e., `eof()` needs to be set:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); ) {
        std::istringstream in(line);
        std::string command, name;
        if (in >> command) {
            if (command == "getData" && in >> name && (in >> std::ws).eof()) {
                std::cout << "getData: read one argument: '" << name << '\n';
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "wrong format on line '" << line << "'\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```